# Are reference requests or solicitations for book recommendations allowed?

Tags: discussion

I am a lay person, not a historian.  Specifically, I'm a scientist.  I am looking to find book recommendations to help me answer (or at least explore) rather broad historical questions.  Examples of historical questions I have are:

- How did the Americans win the American Revolution?
- What were the causes of the American Civil War?  (Short answers I learned in high school are "slavery," "states' rights," and "economics."  But in what ways did these factors play off one another?)
- In what ways did Nazism influence, distort, or mute the teachings and operation of the Christian church, both Roman Catholic and Protestant, in Germany and its occupied territories in 1932-1945?  (This topic was never taken up in my education.  The film *A Hidden Life* (2019) by director Terrence Malick has left me wanting to know more about the Christian church in Germany, Austria, etc in the World War II era.)
- Why did Hitler invade the Soviet Union?  Why did he choose to invade the Soviet Union while the Battle of Britain was still being fought?

Clearly, these are broad topics about which countless volumes have been written.  But I'm looking for individual books that will help me explore these questions in my free time on a level that I can understand.  I don't have time to read volumes and volumes or sift through primary sources.

**Are reference requests or solicitations for book recommendations allowed on History SE?**  I realize that SE prefers questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

If such questions are not allowed, does anyone know of a forum where such questions can be asked (and answered by humans, not AI)?

Comment: I think the last meta Q we had about this (which itself contains a handy list of previous meta questions on the subject) was this one: https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/requests-for-references . General gist is that if the question is if there's a canonical reference on the subject it might be on-topic, but "What are your favorite books about *X*" aren't, because every answer is equally right (unless the answer is lying about their favorites I guess). [SE's format doesn't really work for list questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)